# I am getting "Can't import the named export 'memory'.'buffer' (imported as 'wasm') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, automerge

How can I resolve this error?

> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/@automerge/automerge-wasm/bundler/automerge_wasm_bg.js
> 27:40-58 Can't import the named export 'memory'.'buffer' (imported as
> 'wasm') from default-exporting module (only default export is
> available)

I am a newbie in React and Nodejs.